# Comparing datetimes in php

Tags: php

I am comparing a date with a datetime and I get the result I expect however I also am wondering if there is a better way to display my output and I have a query on my current output also.

Here is a snippet of my current code:

```
<?php

$todayDate = date('Y-m-d');

$seconds = strtotime($todayDate) - strtotime($dueDate);
$hours = $seconds / 60 / 60;
echo number_format($hours, 2);
?>
```

in my case `$dueDate` in my database here is `2017-06-26 09:11:28` so the output is displaying as `-57.19`. My question, is there is a clean way to strip the `-` and also add `h` after the hours and `m` after the minutes so the output looks like this?

`57h 19m`

*UPDATE*

So After tinkering around I have managed to do this:

`substr($dateFormat,0,3).'h '.substr($dateFormat,4).'m';`

The output now is `-57h 19m`

I still have this negative character, im not sure if that is actually correct I cannot seem to work it out because the date in my database is a day ahead but it shows a negative value...

Comment: Maybe https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff pull it in minute, multiple by 60. Also note `.19` is not 19 minutes, it is 11.4 minutes. `.19 * 60`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean sorry?

Comment: Send `$dueDate` with your query then let the DB do the math... or if with the math the decimal part is from a piece of 60, not 100.

Comment: Your update is going the wrong way, what if there is only a 1 hour difference or a 100+ hour difference?

Comment: Yes I can see your point - I am really struggling with this one hmmmm

Comment: Not that it's not worth it to work it out manually, but you might try [Moment.php](https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php), which is based on [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: I wanna try and avoid bringing in a lib because of one compare

Comment: Here's a very hacky approach if you really dont wanna use a lib. https://eval.in/821790

Comment: @danjbh - There is no way for me to know how in-depth you are in your needs, or what level of abstraction you require. YMMV.

Comment: @JaredFarrish of course and I know it :)

Comment: If you want to convert a negative number to a positive number use absolute function which is built in in PHP like so abs(-10). Yields 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the DateTime class makes it very simple

```
$dueDate = '2017-06-26 09:11:28';

$due = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dueDate);
$today = new DateTime();

$diff = $today->diff($due);

echo $diff->format('%hh %im');
```

Result:

```
11h 37m
```

But as you asked about timezones, here is how to add those in as well. And also as you orignial date was in fact some days distant I added a more accurate difference output

```
$dueDate = '2017-06-25 00:00:00';

$due = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dueDate, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$today = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

$diff = $today->diff($due);

echo $diff->format('%R %hh %im').PHP_EOL;

if ( $diff->invert ) {
    echo $diff->format('Overdue by %dd %hh %im');
} else {
    echo $diff->format('You have %dd %hh %im till overdue');
}
```

Results

```
+ 1h 6m
You have 0d 1h 6m till overdue
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thought I would keep it simple and step by step as I assumed this was the OP's first intro to the DateTime class

Comment: @danjbh That because of my local timezone is BST but this is calced in UTC

Comment: I changed the variable `$dueDate`(2017-06-25 00:00:00 in my database column) and the time here is 22:50pm and the output form your code is: 0h 10m

Comment: Is there a way it ca understand when the clocks go back and forth?

Comment: @danjbh - I've had better luck sometimes seeding time from the database through the query, so the compare is against the same clock.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how this can be achieved or a resource I could look at?

Comment: @danjbh Let me back up: How is the date/timestamp generated? If it's from your server using PHP, use PHP and set the timezone (as RiggFolly shows in the edit). If it's MySQL, you should be able to get the same thing with [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and [`TIMEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) (I believe). The method I was describing was using [setTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) with a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` from a query.

Comment: And if it's stored _as a unix timestamp_, you should be able to do it in either MySQL or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep date integer

```
$time = time();
```

after

you can use this every where and evert way

For example

```
$date1 = time();
$date2 = time();

$comparingdate = $date2 - $date1;

$myFormat = date("T-m-d h:i:s",$comparingdate); // Show how you want
```

Comment: So in regards my data above how would this translate? So will `time()` give me a `now` timestamp? I Do not see how I can compare a datetime with the time() function?

Comment: @danjbh `strtotime` would convert to the correct format. This is basically what you already have though.

Answer (score 0):

use floor and round functions to get the minutes and hours after convert the date to positive sign using abs function

```
<?php
    $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
    $dueDate = "2017-06-26 09:11:28";
    $seconds =abs(strtotime($todayDate) - strtotime($dueDate));
    $hours =floor($seconds / 60 / 60);
    $minutes= round($seconds / 60 / 60 - $hours,2)*100;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $hours. " H :";
    echo $minutes. " M ";
    ?>
```